# Laravel - Delete not showing flash error message when it returns else

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this code to delete tables on conditions:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try 
    {          
        $identity = Identity::findOrFail($id);
        if($identity->goals->count() == 0) {
            $identity->parameter()->delete(); 
            $identity->delete();
            Session::flash('success', 'deleted successfully.');
            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            Session::flash('error', 'You cannot delete this data. Goals exists!');
            return redirect()->back();
        }            
    } 
    catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('error', 'delete failed!.');
            return redirect()->back();
    }       
}
```

The

```
if($identity->goals->count() == 0)
```

displays the flash message
while the

```
else {
```

did not display the flash message

How do I get this corrected?

Thanks

Comment: this works for me `return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'delete failed!.');` and on your blade `@if (Session::has('error') {{ Session::get('error') }} @endif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document for [flash session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) for laravel 5.8.

Your controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try
    {
        $identity = Identity::findOrFail($id);
        if($identity->goals->count() == 0) {
            $identity->parameter()->delete();
            $identity->delete();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'deleted successfully.');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'You cannot delete this data. Goals exists!');
        }
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'delete failed!.');
    }
}
```

and your view

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ session('success') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif

@if (session('error'))
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {{ session('error') }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```